# Gnome 3 dependencies trouble

Tags: linux, desktop, gnome, gentoo

I'm having trouble installing Gnome 3, from this web: http://oleeekchoff.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/gnome-3-on-gentoo.html

I already have Gnome 2, so i get this when i try to emerge -avuND world

**Conflict: 7 blocks (4 unsatisfied)**

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled 
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

sys-fs/udev:0

(sys-fs/udev-171-r9::gentoo, installed) pulled in by

(sys-fs/udev-195::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by

> =sys-fs/udev-187 required by (sys-fs/udev-init-scripts-17-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) 
>       (and 1 more with the same problem)

Comment: Forums @gentoo.org are a better place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict means that different packages are requiring different versions of `sys-fs/udev`. In your case for example, the version 171-r9 is the current version on your machine. Some other packages require version 195. The package `udev-init-scripts` requires version 187. Multiple versions of the same package are not allowed unless they are in the different slots.

When installing Gnome 3, there would be many packages that may require different versions of the same package. One walkaround is to use `equery g <package>` to check the packages it depends on, and `equery d <package>` to check which packages requires this package. Locate the package causing conflict and try removing some flags in `/etc/portage/make.conf` and `/etc/portage/package.use`, or masking some packages in `/etc/portage/package.mask`. Solving these conflicts when installing Gnome 3 is much fun compared to using it. Good luck.